# "Find" the ul li's nested in a ul li

Tags: jquery

im having trouble ***selecting*** the `ul` `-->` `li's` nested inside a `div` that resides inside a parent `ul` `-->` `li`. Here is my code:

```
// Navigation
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Click function

    $(".sidebar ul li a").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('open').find("ul.submenu").stop("true", "true").slideDown().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open').find("ul.submenu").stop("true", "true").slideUp().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings("ul.submenu.ul.li a").removeClass('open'); //<-- This is not working.
    });

    $(".sidebar ul li ul li a").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

I commented the part is that is not working, all the rest is working fine.
Basically the first function adds the class ***`.open`*** to the clicked `li`, and opens the nested div containing the child `ul`, the next line removes the class and closes the `div` if another `li` is clicked.

The second group handles adding and removing open class from the ul li ul li's.

The problem is in the third function of the first group, wich is supposed to remove the open class from all ul li ul li's when an ul li is clicked.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $(".sidebar ul li ul li a") i think these kind of selectors are very slow. Try $("somthing").find("..."); or use a context $("somthing", document.getElementById("id"));

Comment: @user874774 ill look into it, im very new to all this, thank you for your imput!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you should note that your second click binding is unnecessary as the elements you want to target with `".sidebar ul li ul li a"` are already targeted by `".sidebar ul li a"` since you're not using the direct descendant selector `>`, and since you're performing the same actions in both functions you can just remove it.

Also as Arun commented in his answer, you're using the class selector instead of the descendant selector, but still I don't believe fixing that will give you the result you want. I believe doing this will work for you:

```
$(".sidebar ul li a").on("click", function() {
    $(".open").not($(this).parents('li')).removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().addClass('open').find("ul.submenu").stop("true", "true").slideDown().addClass('active');
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("ul.submenu").stop("true", "true").slideUp().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, and your code works perfectly except for the same reason why was i trying to make that overly complicated code work :) The problem now is that it will remove .open from ul li's when an ul li ul li is clicked. Basically when a sub-li is .open its parent li should also be .open, for display purposes.